# Java reuse Dimension objects when setting component size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, single-instance

Is it contraindicated to use several presetted dimension objects to set the preferred size of non resizable components on the screen.
E.g.: two textfields both should be 80x20 px so:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(80, 20);
tf1.setPreferredSize(d);
tf2.setPreferredSize(d);
```

Comment: The real question is: should you really call `setPreferreedSize()` on a `JTextField` (or any Swing `JComponent`)? The answer is NO, it is a very bad practice.

Comment: "In medicine, a contraindication is a condition or factor that serves as a reason to withhold a certain medical treatment."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is "safe". Quote from [Java Performance Tuning](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html):

> [...] *This same Dimension object can be reused for multiple components.* [...]

Depends on what you want though. Note that the implementation in `Component` does not copy the content of the argument, but stores the reference:

```
public void setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize) {
    ...
    this.prefSize = preferredSize;
    ...
}
```

so changing `d` will affect the dimension object stored in both `tf1` and `tf2`.

(What I'm saying is that the code below may not do what you would expect.)

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(80, 20);
tf1.setPreferredSize(d);

d.width += 1;               // <-- will affect also tf1.
tf2.setPreferredSize(d);
```

Comment: But neither `tf1` *nor* `tf2` will be *notified* when you change `d`, so they can only find out about it "by chance". That's why I think making things like `Dimension` mutable is a bad idea.

Comment: @Joachim, actually Sun making `Dimension`, `Point`, `Rectangle`... mutable was a bad design decision initially, hence now it's up to developers to care about this fact, and code defensively against mutability of instances of such classes.

Comment: I don't think the question primarily was primarily about "what happens if I modify the dimension object". The question was more on whether or not it is considered safe. My mentioning of "changing `d`" was to clarify that he can't do `tf1.setPrefSize(d); d.width += 5; tf2.setPrefSize(d);`.